# How to do an 'Onclick' trigger that will display data under an ID?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I currently have three tables. One is housekeeping_employee, second one is housekeeping_benefit, and the third one is the housekeeping_employeebenefits. housekeeping_Employeebenefits is my table  where a benefit is assigned/inserted to an employee. Here's my code for displaying the housekeeping_employee in a dropdown, displaying the housekeeping_benefit in checkboxes, and lastly the submit button for the employeebenefits to insert the benefits into the employee.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<form method ='POST' action='' >";
        $ctr = 0;
        $employee = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM housekeeping_employee") or DIE("Could not Select");
    echo    "<select class='indent' name = 'Employee'>";
    echo    "<option>Select</option>";
    while($listEmployee = mysqli_fetch_array($employee))
    {
        echo "<option value = ".$listEmployee['employeeid'].">".$listEmployee['firstname']."</option>";
    }
    echo    "</select>";
        echo    "<br><br>";
        echo    "<div class='indent'>";
        $benefits = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM housekeeping_benefit")or DIE("SELECT Query not working.");   
            if(mysqli_num_rows($benefits))
            {

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($benefits))
                {
                    $ctr++;
                    echo "<h6><input type = 'checkbox' name = 'benefits".$ctr."' value ='".$row['benefitid']."' >".$row['benefitname']." </input></h6> <br>";
                    if($ctr == 5){
                    echo"<br>";
                    $ctr=0;
                    }
                }
                    echo "<br><input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='insert' value='Submit'/>";                
            }

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='ctr' value='".$ctr."'/>";
        echo "</form>";
} 
                else
            {
                $employeeid = $_POST['Employee'];

                for($a = 1; $a <= $_POST['ctr'] ; $a++)
                {
                    if(isset($_POST['benefits'.$a]))
                    {
                        $benefitid = $_POST['benefits'.$a];
                        //echo "INSERT INTO `housekeeping_employeebenefits`(`employeeid`,`benefitid`) VALUES('$employeeid','$benefitid')";

                        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `housekeeping_employeebenefits`(`employeeid`,`benefitid`) VALUES('$employeeid','$benefitid')") or DIE("Insert query is not working");
                        echo "Employee to Benefits successful!";
                    }
                }
            }
?>
```

I did a join query so I can see the benefits under the employee. Here's my query

```
SELECT * FROM housekeeping_employee A,housekeeping_benefit B,housekeeping_employeebenefits C where (A.employeeid = A.employeeid and B.benefitid = C.benefitid) and A.employeeid = 2
```

My friend suggested that I use an onclick which I've never heard or used before so my main question is really far from what I have at the moment but here it is. So from my original code I plan to remove the code that displays all checkboxes of benefits and instead replace it with only displaying the checkboxes of benefits that the employee has. How do I do a trigger that will display the benefit checkboxes under the employee when I choose/click an employee from the dropdown?

**EDIT:**
If onclick is not what I need, what syntax/command do I need?

Comment: `onClick` events are handled by the runtime environment, such as JavaScript and not by PHP.

Comment: What syntax/command should I look for? @mwieczorek

Comment: I'd start by researching jQuery and some general Javascript tutorials. Try YouTube.